# how to write failing junit test case for retrofit implementation

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to do TDD, in which when I am writing test case for getting data from api I am not able to make it fail first.

As per the rule in TDD

1.write test cases(which should fail)

2.update the code and make the failing test pass

3.refactor code

When I am writing test case(#1) testGetCountriesData is not failing probably doing something wrong could you help me by showing me correct way to test?

class which I want to test, I have purposely not initiated NetworkServiceApi api.

```
class NetworkService {
    NetworkServiceApi api;
    public NetworkService() {}

    public Single<List<CountriesApiResponse>> getCountriesData() {
        return api.getCountriesFromApi();
    }
}
interface NetworkServiceApi {
    @GET(Utility.GET_COUNTRIES)
    Single<List<CountriesApiResponse>> getCountriesFromApi();
}
```

My Test case as follows which needs to fail at first but getting success

```
public class NetworkServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    NetworkService service;

    @Mock
    NetworkServiceApi api;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this).close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCountriesData() {
        Single<List<CountriesApiResponse>> countrySingle = Single
                .just(getJsonResponse("/Android_Projects/CountryApp/app/src/main/assets/expectedResponse.json"));
        Mockito.when(api.getCountriesFromApi()).thenReturn(countrySingle);
        Single<List<CountriesApiResponse>> serviceCountriesData = service.getCountriesData();
        List<CountriesApiResponse> responseList = serviceCountriesData.blockingGet();
        Assert.assertEquals(3,responseList.size());
    }

    private List<CountriesApiResponse> getJsonResponse(String filePath) {
        File dir = new File(filePath);
        Type REVIEW_TYPE = new TypeToken<List<CountriesApiResponse>>() {
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(dir));
            List<CountriesApiResponse> data = gson.fromJson(reader, REVIEW_TYPE); // contains the whole reviews list
            return data; // prints to screen some values
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies from gradle file

```
    //retrofit
    def retrofitVersion = "2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"

    //dagger
    def daggerVersion = "2.30.1"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

    //mockito
    def mockitoInlineVersion = "3.6.28"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoInlineVersion"

    //rxjava
    def rxJavaVersion = "2.1.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"
```

Comment: Could you please add all used maven dependencies (e.g. mockito...) in order to reproduce it?

Comment: @HansWurst updated dependencies.